# How to align <div align="left"> and <div align="right"> on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align  and  on the same horizontal line.
This is the code I have so far, adopting suggestions from @Santa's Little Helper.

HTML:

```
<div class="table-holder left-table">
    <Table striped bordered hover></Table>
</div>
<div class="table-holder right-table">
    <Table striped bordered hover></Table>
</div>
<div class="table-holder left-table">
    <Table striped bordered hover></Table>
</div>
<div class="table-holder right-table">
    <Table striped bordered hover></Table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table-holder {
    width:50%;
}
.left-table {
    float:left;

}
.right-table {
    float:right;
}
.table-holder table {
    width:100%;
}
```

This is the output I got: [image]

I wonder how could I put first two tables in one line and last two tables in one line. Ideally, the table on the upper right hand side occupy the same space as the table on the upper left hand side.

Comment: Set some width to the divs. Also, <div> is a block element, so set them to display: inline;

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I did the first one suggested. Everything now is align to the left.

Comment: You mean, you want to have 2 tables on the same line, and then another 2 tables on the next line?

Comment: you got correct output for what you wrote the CSS, please attach an image of your desired result.

Comment: Hi @Santa'sLittleHelper, that's right!

Comment: you need to give 50% width to your table

Comment: offtopic, but have you looked at using Bootstrap v4? why even use table html elements, just div with .table class in bootstrap. and with bootstrap you can align easy using flex boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could achieve this. You can try using floats.
**Method 1:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-holder left-table">
  <Table striped bordered hover></Table>
</div>
<div class="table-holder right-table">
  <Table striped bordered hover></Table>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="table-holder left-table">
  <Table striped bordered hover></Table>
</div>
<div class="table-holder right-table">
  <Table striped bordered hover></Table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table-holder {
  width:50%;
}
.left-table {
  float:left;
}
.right-table {
  float:right;
}
.clear {clear:both;}
.table-holder table {width:100%;}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8cwmuho2/)

**Method 2 (Flex):**

```css
.tables-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tables-container > div {
  flex: 0 50%;
}
.tables-container table {
  width: 100%;
}

/* --- */
table {border:1px solid black;}
table th {border:1px solid red;}
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables-container">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><th>1</th><th>2Z</th></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><th>1</th><th>2D</th></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><th>1</th><th>2B</th></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
other content
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Santa'sLittleHelper, thanks for your help. I made the following changes, but now the second, third, and fourth column on all on the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: @SkipperLin what UI library are you using?

Comment: Hi @Santa'sLittleHelper, I did not think I use any specific UI library.

Comment: Hi @Santa'sLittleHelper, I just modified the question to reflect the changes using your suggestion.

Comment: @SkipperLin I've edited my post, and added another solution using Flex

Comment: That's sweet! It worked greatly. By any chance, how could I keep the table on the top right hand side have the sane height as the table on the top left hand side?

Comment: Also updated my 1st way, should be working as well.

Comment: @SkipperLin add `height:100%;` to `.tables-container table`. (Only using 2nd method)

Comment: Hi @Santa'sLittleHelper, adding ```height:100%;``` did not work. It did not make the table on the top right corner as large as the table on the top left corner. It only shortens the gap between the tables on the top left and bottom left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203558/discussion-between-santas-little-helper-and-skipper-lin).